# Internal error occurred: failed to call webhook

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I tried to install `cert-manager` as a helm chart on my cluster, which has ubuntu 22.04 server, running k8s 1.22.13:

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.9.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

But in the `cert-manager-startupapicheck` pod I do get this error in the logs:

```
Not ready: the cert-manager webhook deployment is not ready yet
Not ready: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.111.115.80:443: i/o timeout
Not ready: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

Also, if running `kubectl apply -f deploy/cert-manager/cluster-issuers.yaml`, it doesn't work:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "deploy/cert-manager/cluster-issuers.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.111.115.80:443: i/o timeout
```

What do these error messages mean?

**Update**

```
kubectl get all -n cert-manager

NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/cert-manager-7b8d75c477-mhvgt              1/1     Running   1 (88m ago)   124m
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-6cd8d7f84b-wxckp   1/1     Running   1 (88m ago)   124m
pod/cert-manager-webhook-64d76db6c-88hzs       1/1     Running   0             124m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.100.239.202   <none>        9402/TCP   124m
service/cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.111.115.80    <none>        443/TCP    124m

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cert-manager              1/1     1            1           124m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           124m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           124m

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-7b8d75c477              1         1         1       124m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-6cd8d7f84b   1         1         1       124m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-64d76db6c       1         1         1       124m

NAME                                     COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/cert-manager-startupapicheck   0/1           123m       123m
```

Comment: There might be a Kubernetes service network problem, where the cert-manager's [MutatingWebhookConfiguration](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/blob/master/deploy/charts/cert-manager/templates/webhook-mutating-webhook.yaml#L40) cannot reach the cert-manager-webook service endpoint.

Comment: Consider adding `kubectl get all -n cert-manager`

Comment: check this , may help https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4646